# Trying to clean up survey results with multiple name entries, some answers given as NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to clean up some odd survey data, which I have created an example of below:

```
test1 = ['sean','tom','dan','sean']
test2 = ['Y',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
test3 = [np.nan,'Y','N','N']

df = pd.DataFrame({'name':test1,'a':test2,'b':test3})

print(df)

   name    a    b
0  sean    Y  NaN
1   tom  NaN    Y
2   dan  NaN    N
3  sean  NaN    N
```

I want to have the results combined so that 'sean' only appears once (so unique values only in the name column) and the answers from both entries of the name have been combined as such:

```
   name    a    b
0  sean    Y    N
1   tom  NaN    Y
2   dan  NaN    N
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is always only one non missing value or all missing values per groups is possible use [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df = df.groupby('name', as_index=False, sort=False).first()
print(df)
   name    a  b
0  sean    Y  N
1   tom  NaN  Y
2   dan  NaN  N
```

Comment: Ah fantastic - that did it! Thank you